# JQuery doesn't get form input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following code to call controller action using ajax and render partial view using kendo window but it doesn't get form elements.

in my view i used this button

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("textButton")
            .Content("Text button")
            .HtmlAttributes( new {type = "button"} )
            .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick")))
```

and kendo window

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("ValidateAddress")
                .Title(@Localizer["Validate Address"].Value)
                .Visible(false)
                .Modal(true)
                .Draggable(true)
                .Width(500)
)
```

and here jQuery looks like

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        function onClick(e) {                
            var getAddress = {                             
                AddressLine1: $('#AddressLine1').val(),
                AddressLine2: $('#AddressLine2').val(),
                City: $('#City').val()
            };
            var window = $("#ValidateAddress").data("kendoWindow");
            var PopUpTitle = "Validate Address ";
                window.setOptions({
                    title: PopUpTitle,
                    content: ""
                });

                window.refresh({
                    url: "/Address/Address/VerifyAddress",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(getAddress),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                });
                window.open();
                window.center();
        }

        $("#textButton").kendoButton({
            click: onClick
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post html generated of above code i.e : button and window ?

Comment: @Swati added thee whole form

Comment: Did you check if `$('#AddressLine1').val()` ..etc these are having any values ? Also does the function gets called or not ? Put an alert and see if that function gets called or not .

Comment: @Swati i added alert next `function onClick(e) {` as `var at = $('#AddressLine1').val();       alert(at);` and it returns the correct value

Comment: Thats good ,Now check your network tab in browser if the ajax request is made and its successfull or not .

Comment: @Swati it works perfect `Status code:200K` and i can see view returned from the controller in response but empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220535/discussion-between-swati-and-rob).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Kendo does not uses the id attribute, but the asp-for. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function onClick(e) {                
        var getAddress = {                             
            AddressLine1: $('[asp-for=AddressLine1]').val(),
            AddressLine2: $('[asp-for=AddressLine2]').val(),
            City: $('#City').val()
        };
        var window = $("[asp-for=ValidateAddress]").data("kendoWindow");
        var PopUpTitle = "Validate Address ";
        window.setOptions({
            title: PopUpTitle,
            content: ""
        });

        window.refresh({
            url: "/Address/Address/VerifyAddress",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(getAddress),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
        window.open();
        window.center();
    }

    $("[asp-for=textButton]").kendoButton({
    click: onClick
    });
});
```

Or, maybe, you could try to "compatibilize" the Kendo with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let adjustArray = $("[asp-for]:not([id])");
    adjustArray.each( index => {
        let el = $(adjustArray[index]);
        el.attr('id', el.attr('asp-for'));
    });
    function onClick(e) {                
        var getAddress = {    
            ... continuation of your code
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt like it

Comment: I'm sorry but i missunderstood. You don't liked the answer? Or you cant like the answer? If you liked and worked, please, set 'answered' in your question :)

Comment: If you don't liked, i'm sorry :(

Comment: No i'm sorry, i tried it but the app doesn't like [asp-for], i didn't mean i didn't like you solution sorry. I really thank you for the help, i am still trying it but still post empty